# Call Jquery Ajax Async Method while Redirecting to Another page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, redirect

I have Asp:Login Control on login page to login, after successfully login it redirects to another application.

I am doing two process **parallel**. 1) **Redirection** and  2) **Call jQuery Asynchronous Ajax**

So, i am doing **Jquery ajax Asynchronous** call to do some async process (Success method metters for me) before Login (I have set ajax call on OnClientClick of Login Button).
On **server  side click event** of Login Button is **redirecting to Another page** (with `Response.redirect()`).
When Ajax call is calling and it takes more time to complete, and after complete, i need to update some process.

Here is my problem, I can't get Success method of ajax, It means **Jquery Ajax Call failed on redirect**.

here i can't take redirect with Javascript `Windows.load` function.

**Is it possible this or any suggestion to do this stuff ?**

Thanks in advance.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

When user clicks submit button on a page (such as "Login") all pending AJAX calls are Cancelled (you can see it in browser console). What you can do is execute synchronous AJAX call (browser will wait for it to finish):

```
jQuery.ajax({
         url:    'YourService',
         success: function(result) {
                      if(result.isOk == false)
                          alert(result.message);
                  },
         async:   false
    });
```

If AJAX call is very long you can try opening new window and executing AJAX call from it. I know its messy but it might work.